# How to repeat the function N times per second?

Tags: go

How to repeat the function N times per second in Go?

I can:

```
N := 30 //Repeat 30 times per second
for {
    //Do something
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(N))
}
```

But that just makes the intervals between repetitions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options, neither will get you a guaranteed x times per second.

- Set N not to `30` but `1/30`. Thus the sleep will be for 1/30th of a second.
- Have an internal for-loop that loops 30 times and executes your 'do something', and then on exit you hit the statement that sleeps for a second.

Option One:

```
N := 30 //Repeat 30 times per second
for {
    //Do something
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(1e9 / N))  //time.second constant unnecessary (see kostya comments)
}
```

Option Two:

```
N := 1  //Sleep duration of one second
for {
    for i := 1;  i<=30; i++ {
        //Do something
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(N))
}
```

Note that in option two, everything happens all at once, and then you wait a second. The first option will space out the do something across the second. Because of timing in computers this won't be precise: sleep cannot guarantee it will wake up precisely when you expect.

Comment: `time.Second * time.Duration(1/N)` is 0, it should be `time.Duration(1e9 / N)`

Comment: Ah, good point! I'm pretty new to Go: my apologies. Thank you for the pointer!

Comment: Sorry, you've got it wrong again. Please read the docs ;) `time.Duration(1)` is 1 nano second. In the second example it should be `time.Sleep(time.Second)`

Comment: I think I caught that already: I realized pretty fast that edit was erroneous. :)

Comment: I think you want to measure the amount of time "Do something" takes and sleep for 1/30s - that time, otherwise, your overall frequency is guaranteed to be less than 30Hz.

Comment: I assumed that tuning was beyond the scope of the question. Certainly it's not specified if it needs to happen 'about' 30 times a second, exactly 30 times a second (nearly impossible) or 'at least' 30 times a second.

Comment: @NathanielFord it's not nearly impossible (to get *extremely* close to 30 times a second), it's trivially easy with a `time.Ticker`. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`time.Ticker`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker) to handle all the book-keeping for you. The only "issue" is that if your operation takes longer than expected you'll loose ticks (and thus run fewer than N per second).

```
func doSomething() {
    const N = 30
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second / N)
    for range ticker.C {
        fmt.Println("Do anything that takes no longer than 1/Nth of a second")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Gq-tWMvxIk

Comment: Note that this works correctly no matter if the operation takes <1 nanosecond or 33 milliseconds or anywhere in between. (Except that `time.Second` doesn't exactly divide into 30 so it'll do ~30.0000003/sec).